# How can I add leading 0's to a char?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing an export for a client and they are requesting that each column be exactly 10 characters long.  In the exoprt I have a column that is formatted as char(10) that is our invoice number but is only 6 characters long so I need to add 3 leading 0's. This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT '000'+invno, invdte, '000'+item, brnkcomp, tqtyshp,price, bextpri, descrip
FROM artran a
LEFT JOIN arcust b ON a.custno = b.custno
WHERE invdte BETWEEN DATEADD("d",-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() AND item IN ('10120','1000290','30234','10491','10747','21449')
```

But the reult for that always has a space between the 0's and the invoice number.  I can't have the space.

```
000   6325290
000   6325301
000   6325331
000   6325357
000   6325369
000   6325400
```

I have also tried this with the same results of having a space between the 0's and the invoice #

```
SELECT LEFT('000'+CAST(invno AS VARCHAR(15)),15) 
FROM artran a
LEFT JOIN arcust b ON a.custno = b.custno
WHERE invdte BETWEEN DATEADD("d",-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() AND item IN ('10120','1000290','30234','10491','10747','21449')

000   6325290
000   6325301
000   6325331
000   6325357
000   6325369
000   6325400
```

I would like the output to look like these results:

```
0006325290
0006325301
0006325331
0006325357
0006325369
0006325400
```

I am running this export in SSRS so if there is a way to do it there easier I could also do it that way. Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `invno`?

Comment: char = fixed length and pads w/ spaces varchar = variable length no spaces... so if you want to add 000's  RIGHT('0000000000'+ISNULL(trim(field),''),10)

Comment: That was it....thanks xQBert!

Answer (score 3):

you can use Format(column, 'D10') as below

```
 SELECT Format(invno, 'D10') as InvNo, invdte, '000'+item, brnkcomp, tqtyshp,price, bextpri, descrip
 FROM artran a
LEFT JOIN arcust b ON a.custno = b.custno
WHERE invdte BETWEEN DATEADD("d",-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() AND item IN 
  ('10120','1000290','30234','10491','10747','21449')
```

Other way is to do right and cast:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000'+CAST(InvNo AS VARCHAR(10)),10)...
```

Comment: While FORMAT is great it does have performance implications and your second method of RIGHT(... would significantly out preform the other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function is only available in SQL Server 2012 and forward. So that will not work for you in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I think the issue with what you have tried is that you have leading spaces in `invno`. Get rid of them with `LTRIM` and any trailing spaces can be removed with `RTRIM`. Then to pad your value with zeroes just concatenate them to the left side and then take the rightmost number of characters you want. In your case, 10. If you are absolutely sure that the values you are dealing with are always a set number of characters you could get by with only adding the number you need. However, the method I have shown here will account for varying lengths of the original value.

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(invno)), 10) as InvNo, invdte, '000'+item, brnkcomp, tqtyshp,price, bextpri, descrip
FROM artran a
LEFT JOIN arcust b ON a.custno = b.custno
WHERE invdte BETWEEN DATEADD("d",-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE() AND item IN 
  ('10120','1000290','30234','10491','10747','21449')
```

Noel